# Entity Framework 6, Oracle - Linq Join Query generates unwanted where condition

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, entity-framework-6

I have the following arrangement where I join 2 tables to retrieve a description column from the second table.

I am using Entity Framework 6 with Oracle 12c

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    return this.dbSet.AsQueryable();
}

var fooQuery = fooRepo.GetAll();
var barQuery = barRepo.GetAll();

var joinedQuery = 
    fooQuery.Join(
    barQuery,
    fooObj => new { fooObj.comp_key_1, fooObj.comp_key_2, fooObj.comp_key_3 },
    barObj => new { barObj.comp_key_1, barObj.comp_key_2, barObj.comp_key_3 },
    (fooItem, barItem) => new {
        fooItem.comp_key_1,
        fooItem.comp_key_2,
        fooItem.comp_key_3,
        ...
        ...
        ...
        barItem.BarName
    }
);
```

When executed the code it generates the following SQL which is less that ideal as there is an unintended where clause being generated.

```
SELECT 
    1 AS "C1", 
    "Extent1"."COMP_KEY_1" AS "COMP_KEY_1", 
    "Extent1"."COMP_KEY_2" AS "COMP_KEY_2", 
    "Extent1"."COMP_KEY_3" AS "COMP_KEY_3", 
    ...
    ...
    ...
    "Extent2"."BAR_NAME" AS "BAR_NAME"
FROM  "FOO_TABLE" "Extent1"
INNER JOIN "BAR_TABLE" "Extent2" ON ("Extent1"."COMP_KEY_1" = "Extent2"."COMP_KEY_1") AND ("Extent1"."COMP_KEY_2" = "Extent2"."COMP_KEY_2") AND ("Extent1"."COMP_KEY_3" = "Extent2"."COMP_KEY_3")
WHERE ((("Extent2"."Discriminator" = N'Foo') OR ("Extent2"."Discriminator" = N'Bar')))
```

What am I missing, what needs to be done to remove the unintended where Clause ?

Answer (score 0):

Found it,

Had a base class for 'Bar' that contains only the p_key information and an extended class that contained all other properties.

Once I moved everything in to a single class

```
("Extent2"."Discriminator" = N'Foo') OR ("Extent2"."Discriminator" = N'Bar')
```

disappeared